Convert a List<Pojo> to a CSV String with Headers
I hope someone can help with the following: I have an Arraylist of
List<Transaction> transactions; 

with fields:
private String firmId; 
private String accountId; 
private String symbol; 
private long quantity;

That I want to convert to the following CSV formatted String:
firmId,AccountId,symbol, quantity
1234,ACCOUNT1,AAPL,100
1234,ACCOUNT1,AMZN,200
2345,ACCOUNT3,AAPL,400

Is there an efficient and simple way to do this in Java? As I don't want to use OpenCSV and write it to a file. I also don't like the option to use abstraction.
I need to use the CSVString in my program as a payload for another request. The number of objects can be up to 2000 in the List.
Thanks!

basically, you just want a list with Strings?  "title bar" + forEach(line.toString()); should do it, depending on your toString() implementation

If you don't want to use a library, you'll probably have to implement it yourself. There are, however, some great libraries out there who could do the job for you.

if you already know that it will only be those 4 fields, you can implement a toString that joins the fields with commas, then just use a for loop to convert it

Are you asking for any POJO? Or specifically for class Transaction?

@Abra, specifically class Transaction, and the resulting CSV formatted String I posted

Then I think the @BIBOOnation comment is the way to go.

"I also don't like the option to use abstraction." - Care to explain why? If this is just for a simple case like the one you posted then you might not need any library. But if your data might need escaping etc. then building it yourself may be more harmful than using a well tested library that provides some form of abstraction. Or are you referring to some other form of abstraction?

Why don't use OpenCSV without writing to files?

@aled, How would that work as an example? Can you end up with the example String I posted?

In order to obtain the desired string as posted in your question, I suggest the following:

Override method toString, in class Transaction, so that it returns the concatenation of the values of all the attributes of the Transaction instance, delimited by commas.
Instantiate StringBuilder and append the desired title, i.e. firmId,AccountId,symbol, quantity.
Iterate through the list of Transaction instances, calling the toString method on each instance and appending the result to the StringBuilder.

Voilà, you have your desired results.
The below code also handles null valued attributes and adds newline characters, i.e. \n, where necessary.
import java.util.List;

public class Transaction {
    private String firmId; 
    private String accountId; 
    private String symbol; 
    private long quantity;

    public Transaction(String firmId, String accountId, String symbol, long quantity) {
        this.firmId = firmId;
        this.accountId = accountId;
        this.symbol = symbol;
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String firm = firmId == null ? "" : firmId;
        String acct = accountId == null ? "" : accountId;
        String smbl = symbol == null ? "" : symbol;
        return firm + "," + acct + "," + smbl + "," + quantity;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        List<Transaction> list = List.of(new Transaction("1234","ACCOUNT1","AAPL",100),
                                         new Transaction("1234","ACCOUNT1","AMZN",200),
                                         new Transaction("2345","ACCOUNT3","AAPL",400));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("firmId,AccountId,symbol, quantity\n");
        list.forEach(t -> sb.append(t + "\n"));
        System.out.println(sb);
    }
}

Output when running above code:
firmId,AccountId,symbol, quantity
1234,ACCOUNT1,AAPL,100
1234,ACCOUNT1,AMZN,200
2345,ACCOUNT3,AAPL,400

EDIT
You can also use the stream API – rather than method forEach.
(Note that Transaction::toString is a method reference.)
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("firmId,AccountId,symbol, quantity\n");
sb.append(list.stream()
              .map(Transaction::toString)
              .collect(Collectors.joining("\n")));


Thanks, this works great and builds the payload I needed!!
